# Magento 2.4.2 minicart not showing product details

Tags: magento, magento2, minicart

I have a magento 2 store. When a product is added to cart, product details are missing in mini cart. The following is a screenshot of what I am saying;

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution and is now working. The issue was in magento_checkout/web/template/minicart/item/default.phtml.
Instead of

```
<span data-bind="text: option.print_value"></span>
```

I have changed it to

```
<span data-bind="text: option.value"></span>
```

And now working fine.